# Am trying to maven install the apache-storm repo i cloned. And am getting the following error. How to resolve this?

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0:check (validate) on project maven-shade-clojure-transformer: Execution validate of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0:check failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.8.0 at specified path C:\Java\jre1.8.0_201/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 1]

Here is the link to the pom.xml
https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: The result of `dir c:\tools.jar /s /b` is ? Do you use a JRE or JDK ? Does your environment point to the jdk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have the JAVA_HOME environment variable set to point to a JRE instead of a JDK. Install a JDK instead, and update JAVA_HOME to point to it (e.g. "C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_201" instead of "C:\Java\jre1.8.0_201")